# ARM Neon: conditional store suggestion

Tags: arm, store, sse, neon, intrinsics

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a conditional Store in ARM neon. What I would like to do is the equivalent of this SSE instruction:

void _mm_maskmoveu_si128(__m128i d, __m128i n, char *p);

which Conditionally stores byte elements of d to address p.The high bit of each byte in the selector n determines whether the corresponding byte in d will be stored.

Any suggestion on how to do it with NEON intrinsics?
Thank you

This is what I did:

```
int8x16_t store_mask = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff};

int8x16_t tmp_dest = vld1q_u8((int8_t*)p_dest);
vbslq_u8(source,tmp_dest,store_mask);
vst1q_u8((int8_t*)p_dest,tmp_dest);
```

Comment: You'll need to do in three steps: load the vector first, use a mask to modify just the required elements, then store the modified vector back to its original location.

Comment: Sorry but it's still not clear to me. What I would like to do is: use a vector like this one :mask={0,0,0,0,0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80}; which is my "n" parameter in the _mm_maskmoveu_si128(__m128i d, __m128i n, char *p); case. How should the mask you talk about be structured? What operations should I do? Thank you (I've never used Neon before so I'm a little bit confused).

Comment: OK - as it's getting complicated I've put a more detailed explanation in the form of an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming vectors of 16 x 1 byte elements, you would set up a mask vector where each element is either all 0s (`0x00`) or all 1s (`0xff`) to determine whether the element should be stored on not. Then you need to do the following (pseudo code):

```
 init mask vector = 0x00/0xff in each element
 init source vector = data to be selectively stored
 load dest vector from dest location
 apply `vbslq_u8` (`vbit` instruction) with dest vector, source vector and mask vector
 store dest vector back to dest location
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement it following your explanation.

Comment: I implemented it following your pseudo code (see the edited question). Is this correct? I've got another doubt. The mask in the original code (with some SSE instructions that I'm trying to convert to ARM Neon) is this: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80};. Is there a reason why 0x80 can be used instead of 0xff? Thank you

Comment: It's just a different instruction set so you have to work with what's available. It's pretty easy to convert the mask between 0x80 and 0xff if you need to (one instruction) - or you might be able to change the code that generates the mask so that this is not necessary.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, I cannot use the same mask used with SSE instructions? To obtain the corresponding one in ARM neon i just have to replace the 0x80 with 0xff?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - the most general form of a mask is all 1s/all 0s. You just need to convert the 0x80 elements to 0xff, which can be done in one instruction if needed (arithmetic shift right by 7 bits).